# Did any type of Orcs reside in Rhun or Harad?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, orcs, middle-earth

We know that Orcs like to reside in mountains, which there is a range of in Rhun. I don't know of any mountains in Harad.

But is there any indication that orcs resided in Rhun or Harad or both?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Ambarkanta maps](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ambarkanta_maps) (published in History of Middle-earth 4) there should be at least one chain of mountains in Harad: the Grey Mountains (not to be confused with the *other* Grey Mountains north of Mirkwood), running along the west coast from north to south.

There is however no evidence that I am aware of for Orcs living in either Rhun or Harad.

A hypothetical case can be made against Orcs living there, which is that Sauron had successfully corrupted most Men from these areas, and so he would have had little need for Orcs.

> In the east and south well nigh all Men were under his dominion, and they grew strong in those days and built many towns and walls of stone, and they were numerous and fierce in war and aimed with iron. To them Sauron was both king and god; and they feared him exceedingly, for he surrounded his abode with fire.

(*Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, and they were "stronger" than the western varieties

In a writing from the last year of Tolkien's life, he explains that one of the reasons why it took Sauron so long to be ready for open war in the Second age is that he needed to time to gain control of the orcs in the East.

Tolkien describes these Eastern orcs as being more numerous and stronger than the westerns types.

> The Orcs of various kind (creatures of Morgoth) were to prove the most numerous and terrible of his soldiers and servants; but great hosts of them had been destroyed in the war against Morgoth, and in the destruction of Beleriand. Some remnant had escaped to hidings in the northern parts of the Misty Mountains and the Grey Mountains, and were now multiplying again. **But further East there were more and stronger kinds, descendants of Morgoth’s kingship, but long masterless during his occupation of Thangorodrim, they were yet wild and ungovernable, preying upon one another and upon Men (whether good or evil).** But not until Mordor and the Barad-dûr were ready could he allow them to come out of hiding, while **the Eastern Orcs, who had not experienced the power and terror of the Eldar, or the valour of the Edain, were not subservient to Sauron** – while he was obliged for the cozening of Western Men and Elves to wear as fair a form and countenance as he could, they despised him and laughed at him.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Note on the Delay of Gil-galad and the Númenóreans"</sub>